# Query 10 times slower using LEFT JOIN CASE in order by

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a relatively long query (posted below for reference).

I have tried to debug why the query is so slow (2 seconds), and I have finally found the cause.

In the end of the query I do:

```
  ORDER BY 
    -- order by date
    DATE(p.date) DESC, 
    -- order by followed people
    CASE WHEN n.id IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE '1' END DESC -- this case takes the query from 20ms to 2 seconds
```

If I remove the CASE order by, it'll execute in around 20 ms.

Why is this?

When I run the query with EXPLAIN, I notice the CASE will add "Using temporary" into the Extra field.

### See EXPLAIN queries below:

Explain query with `CASE WHEN n.id IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE '1' END DESC` in order by

[image: With the CASE statement in the orderby]

Explain query **without** `CASE WHEN n.id IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE '1' END DESC` in order by

[image: Without the CASE statement in the order by]

### The full query (if it may help):

```
  SELECT 
    -- feed type
    '1' AS feed_type, 
    -- fetch post data
    p.id, 
    p.receiver, 
    p.date, 
    p.message, 
    p.system_msg, 
    p.type AS post_type, 
    -- fetch author data
    u.user_id, 
    u.firstname, 
    u.lastname, 
    u.type, 
    u.permalink, 
    av.file AS avatar_file, 
    -- fetch receiever data
    u2.user_id AS receiver_user_id, 
    u2.firstname AS receiver_firstname, 
    u2.lastname AS receiver_lastname, 
    u2.permalink AS receiver_permalink, 
    u2.type AS receiver_type, 
    -- fetch post comment count
    (
      SELECT 
        COUNT(*) 
      FROM 
        edu_posts pc 
      WHERE 
        pc.comment = p.id 
        AND pc.deleted IS NULL
    ) as commentCount, 
    -- fetch post like count
    (
      SELECT 
        COUNT(*) 
      FROM 
        edu_likes l 
      WHERE 
        l.like_entity = p.id
    ) as likeCount, 
    -- user follow state
    CASE WHEN n.id IS NOT NULL THEN '1' ELSE '0' END as is_following, 
    -- check if user likes post
    CASE WHEN l.like_id IS NOT NULL THEN '1' ELSE '0' END as user_likes 
  FROM 
    edu_posts p
    INNER JOIN -- author information
    edu_users u ON u.user_id = p.author 
    LEFT JOIN -- author avatar
    edu_avatars av ON av.fk = p.author 
    AND av.temp = 0 
    AND av.fk_type = 1 
    LEFT JOIN -- receiver information (if any)
    edu_users u2 ON u2.user_id = p.receiver 
    LEFT JOIN -- check if author/receiver is followed by current user
    edu_notification_list n ON n.user = 1 
    AND n.following = 1 
    AND (
      n.fk = p.author 
      OR n.fk = p.receiver
    ) 
    AND (
      (
        n.type = 5 
        AND p.type = 3
      ) 
      OR (
        n.type = 2 
        AND p.type = 1
      )
    ) 
    LEFT JOIN -- check if user likes the post
    edu_likes l ON l.like_entity = p.id 
    AND l.like_author = 1 
  WHERE
    p.deleted IS NULL 
    AND p.comment IS NULL 
    AND (
      p.id = p.comment 
      OR 1 = 1
    ) 
    AND (
      n.id IS NOT NULL 
      OR p.system_msg = 0
    ) 
  ORDER BY 
    -- order by date
    DATE(p.date) DESC, 
    -- order by followed people
    CASE WHEN n.id IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE '1' END DESC 
  LIMIT 
    20 OFFSET 0
```

*NOTE: Please let me know, if you would like to see any of the other tables.*

Comment: your second order field leads MySQL to use `filesort`. That's bad. You could try the suggestion of @juergen_d and check then the result of EXPLAIN anew.

Comment: The answer he provided did not work. Do you have any suggestions? I have tried all day to fix this..

Comment: This may not be relevant but why do you sort by `DATE(p.date)` rather than by `p.date`?

Comment: Because I dont want to order by time.

Answer (score 0):

You perform an operation that can't make use of indexes. Instead try

```
ORDER BY DATE(p.date) DESC, 
         n.id IS NULL ASC
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it does not change anything.